# Multiple dependent modules under same package - Magento

Tags: magento

I am developing a Magento extension(s) with lot of confusions. The Magento Extension(ME) in this respect should a)export orders, b)import products, c)update shipping etc. The common of them is that I have a common 'jobs' table which is used to track all of the sub-modules mentioned above.

That means my ME has to have Model, Sql, Helper etc to communicate with 'jobs' table. Note that a) b) and c) may be optionally installed by users. I am confused as to what should be done to develop a, b and c-

therefore, build a), b) and c) separately but within the same package (i.e. namespace is ME)?
If yes, how many admin modules should I have? One in common? can I use any common class?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Some module developers will also have a 'Core' module which comes bundled with their modules.  I worked with one this morning in fact, you might want to have a look and see how they are handling it - http://innoexts.com/promotions/free/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do build 4 moudles:

1. Export orders
2. Import products
3. Update shipping
4. Custom Data Access

**Depends**

You can force the user to install the Custom Data Access module by adding the following in the module 1,2 and 3 module xml files under app/modules/etc remember to change "Custom_Data" to what ever you use for module 4

```
<depends>
    <Custom_Data />
</depends>
```

**Helper**

You can also deal with interactions by either extending the core module files in the other extensions or you could get the common data that you need through a helper. You can define a helper in your module's config.xml in the  section.

```
<helpers>
    <custom_data>
        <class>Custom_Data_Helper</class>
    </custom_data>
</helpers>
```

**Packaging for release**

You can also define a dependency when packaging an extension for release. With this dependency when a user goes to install the main package they will be instructed to also install the dependency.

Comment: You are great! Thanks for your quick help. Is it possible to access a helper class from another module in this case?

Comment: If you have the depends in place then you should be safe to call $helper = Mage::helper('Customer_Data'); safe in the knowledge that the module is in place.

Comment: I have now edited the answer to include a section on packaging your module for release. I hope this covers what you need.

Comment: I got the real help. Thanks David!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to Magento myself, but it seems to me you could write 4 modules:

1. Export orders
2. Import products
3. Update shipping
4. Custom Data Access

Each of them requires 4 to be installed, but they can all be installed in whatever order/combination otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. It is a nice answer. But please explain me (a) how can I force user install the 4. Custom Data Access module and (b) how should module#1,2 and 3 interact with (4).